# Join tableA.column1 to tableB where tableA.column1 is between tableB.column2 and tableB.column3

Tags: mysql, sql, join, range

I have two tables: `user`, `zone`

```
# user table
CREATE TABLE `customers_users` (
    `userid` INT(10),
    `username` VARCHAR(12),
    `homePhone` VARCHAR(10)
)
# zone table
CREATE TABLE `zone` (
    `id` INT(10),
    `range_from` VARCHAR(10),
    `range_to` VARCHAR(10),
    `zone` VARCHAR(10)
)
```

The `zone` table defines what zones different telephone numbers fall under.

Given a zone table of:

```
| range_from | range_to   | zone   |
| 0260000000 | 0261000000 | Zone 1 |
| 0261000001 | 0262000000 | Zone 2 |
| 0262000001 | 0263000000 | Zone 3 |
```

The following would be the desired result :

```
| homePhone  | zone   |
| 0260000001 | Zone 1 |
| 0260000011 | Zone 1 |
| 0261000001 | Zone 2 |
| 0261000101 | Zone 2 |
| 0262000001 | Zone 3 |
| 0262001001 | Zone 3 |
```

The question is how do I join the user table to the zone table to acquire this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join conditions are quite flexible:

```
select c.homePhone, z.zone
from customers_users as c
join zone as z on c.homePhone between z.range_from and z.range_to
```

Comment: This looks promising. Checking it out now

Comment: Perfect. It is running rather slow but perfectly solves the problem. thanks

Comment: @superspace: A bit of indexing should speed it up.